# Print from a page that doesn't allow any commands?

Tags: pdf, printing

I have opened a webpage that has an article of very much interest to me. When I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or right click, it says, "The page forbids you to use any additional commands."

So now how do I print such a page or save it as a PDF, at the very least?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I tried in chrome,firefox and safari , all latest updated versions, the same problem persists

Comment: Just move the focus away from the page, onto the address bar, or some other browser control. Then you will be able to press CTRL+P, and the website won't stop you ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Some websites prevent you from using keyboard shortcuts because they are worried that you will steal content such as trying to save an image by right-clicking on it. Try using the browser's "Print" option in the top menu, instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or the right-click menu.

### Google Chrome

Click the wrench icon (upper right) and then choose "Print...".
[image: Chrome print]

### Firefox

Click Firefox (upper left), go to "Print..." , and then choose "Print...".
[image: Firefox print]

### Internet Explorer

Click the gear (upper right), go to "Print", and choose "Print...".
[image: IE print]

Comment: haha, i accept this as the answer for the sheer effort you took to place the pics, nevertheless dennis's answer was all the way right too

Comment: @Dennis Sorry, Dennis, but I didn't see your answer when I posted mine. I wouldn't have posted this if I had realized that you had already posted the same thing. I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: @user151203 Thanks for accepting mine. I actually didn't see Dennis's answer until after I posted mine.

Comment: You took the time to make screenshots. That makes you answer different enough in my book.

Comment: What i find interesting is the google doodle is apparently linked to your timezone. I won't spoil tomorrow's one. :-)

Comment: haha, its already changed here, doodle i mean

Comment: @stefan Haha, I had actually just reformatted my PC yesterday, so it was the first time I opened IE. That's why the page shown is MSN.com!

Comment: +1 for +1 comments always getting +1 upvotes because of the +1.

Comment: @stefan what are you talking about, chrome is only a little bit faster than IE...

Comment: @leaf68 relax, it's just a joke. Like "Most people only use IE to download a better browser".

Comment: @stefan OK but I'm just saying, it gets a ton of bull when it's a perfectly good browser

Answer (score 17):

In Chrome, you can click the "hot dogs" icon in the right upper corner and choose **Print...**.

In Firefox, you can click the Firefox icon in the left upper corner and choose **Print...**.

Unless the page requires it to load, you could also disable JavaScript to avoid this and other annoyances:

- In Chrome, open `chrome://chrome/settings/content` and add the hostname to the block list.
- In Firefox, you can temporarily disable JavaScript in **Firefox → Options → Options → Content** or install the [NoScript](http://noscript.net/) extension to block JavaScript for specific sites only.

Comment: wow, that worked, but doesnt doing this and ctrl+p the same,  but how come this doesnt attract any attention from the webpage??

Comment: Most hotkeys can be overridden by JavaScript. See my edit.

Comment: btw, the Wrench icon has been removed in the latest Chrome build. It might come to stable builds in another 6 weeks or so

Comment: @Sathya what's it been replaced with?

Comment: @nhinkle 3 horizontal bars. (I don't know how else to put it :| http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/118?m=5695155#5695155 )

Comment: the same menu icon used in Chrome for Android, i think

Comment: Aside from completely disabling JavaScript, in some similar cases you can block specific behaviour, such as replacing or removing context menus, in Firefox by clicking the "Advanced" button next to the checkbox that allows you to disable JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Take a screenshot (see the accepted answer), crop in image editor to remove browser controls, do whatever you want with the image.

Comment: Cons: much more manual work required. Pros: works with any browser or webbrowser control.

Comment: I resort to this when some pages just refuse to print or leave parts out.  When all else fails, you can always go old school on it and photograph or video your screen with an external camera.  It's not very easily machine readable, but it always works.  Sometimes, but probably not in your case, you can copy and paste the whole thing into a word processor like LibreOffice writer and print from there.